# What additional details are sent to servers with ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, ip, server, user-agent, request-headers

Can PHP/or other server side software tell who sent an ajax get request, things like the user agent or ip geo location if nothing like that is sent in the ajax? I mean, can server technology detect that I have sent using say firefox and that i am in italy without needing me to have sent that info from the client side, or does it need to get that info from being fed through the ajax?

```
$.get(
    'request',
    {
        foo    : 'no user info here',
        action : 'click'
    });
```

**Would the above request also transmit my ip (or anything other than foo or action) in the headers?** When I inspect the headers of a request to say google images in the console > Network > Headers
I see from what I can tell the header sent to me for an image (when I make the request in ajax would something simular be sent to the server)...

```
Remote Address:173.194.40.31:443
Request URL:https://www.google.it/search?q=cat&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=439&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hTLiVMS1KtbtavaugqAB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
:authority:www.google.it
:method:GET
:path:/search?q=cat&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=439&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hTLiVMS1KtbtavaugqAB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=1
:scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
avail-dictionary:e9KXljul
cookie:SID=DQAAABABAAB_FyDDYGPkx5neGQPWarf87-orPHLggOvof1m7ANKPwpxKRc0LBxJpvQqWpvF6_qk2G8rfG-ZIeNkXG6zGES07ZQpIKOxZNfNO_yX4o2VJaK2mWLUtR6alp6ANCVsJhhM9qe5CxTiS5iMsV0ehKtUQyhUe4qgV4ysI-0yNczd-Vf6i2ZwQpjXqP7OkepVDCdxowaWiGTN5oH8gazhEirTkwJHNeXvANPpdnH9agrh807WvnINDfHMabvNMX86yrhDztgJV8Gt93tMKz2mQIrt4U6kkWpVSJRNICz1l-mlqpAroR-0Gh1hkSSQjTljduf0Gw0brc5ghRzZjnUgRx8-R-Utw2a7jtFZZZ8r04sn9mA; HSID=AiyA-7nS0qOcJPXs4; SSID=AOqRsDMDbkeyP70To; APISID=G4pCmX4uO0A42AlZ/Aw1eRZuRDgbTcsS9u; SAPISID=Fyq-DT3qTKlXX0BV/AFeL6M-cBLSA80AMA; NID=67=qSXRNvV7cf8TvEKdQ-hXpivK8o5iB68hmamjpPgcab9LaF2gi8YcLEZ3a0CkZE_YtRA1-xEbcBy6OF5kQQWvsKkh7wfly_zGcT007kA3rtTybNZxAWyc3ZgQw5h5ZcKYB8uh4rMMkqmloRbVJqsGtLni46mjevXs8xQ6qELItYJzwEkuocVE8ZS3nGIkduBPwOnktmEjTQ; PREF=ID=da3065f670165ae8:U=d4b51905e77a1373:FF=4:LD=en:TM=1420582780:LM=1424110248:SG=1:S=_-WZG1_sLNN6wYUA
referer:https://www.google.it/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36
```

I see that the remote address is an ip but the remote url is not. What confuses me is the user agent is sent back to me **or is the above what got sent to the server with my request?**